# Backbone create another view for to do list tutorial

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

The following example works perfectly (http://jsfiddle.net/WmsnR/1/). It's a super basic to do list with no style at all. This is my first attempt to backbone and I have built this based on a tutorial. 
I was told by a senior developer that perhaps I should create another view for each li so that I can attach different events if needed.
So how can I build another view which relates to one that I have previously did?

I have tried something like the following but it didnt work:

```
        var Item = Backbone.View.extend({

            events: {
              'click span': 'deleteTask'
            },  

            deleteTask: function(evt){
                var task = $(evt.currentTarget).closest('li');
                task.remove();
            }       

        });

                   var item = new Item();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember to add the views for each of the models in the calling list.

The overall architecture looks kind of like this:

```
+------------------+
| Parent List View |
|  +-----------+   |
|  | Item View |   |
|  +-----------+   |
|  +-----------+   |
|  | Item View |   |
|  +-----------+   |
+------------------+
```

The parent list view would be a container view that lists out each of the items, creating a view for each of the items.

So, your render for the parent list would look kind of like this:

```
     render: function () {

        // Sort and render each item, starting with a depth of zero.
        _.each(listOfModels,
            function (item) {
                var view = new ItemView({model:item});
                $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
            }, this);

        return this;
    },
```

That's just the rough idea.

Check out the [update to the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmsnR/2/) for specific implementation ideas.

Comment: that actually works very well, although I am still a bit confused about certain things but I guess it's due to the fact that I am very new to Backbone.js. Thanks you I managed to develop my first Backbone.js app (http://alessandrosantese.com/backbone/)

Answer (score 0):

I think on what the senior developer meant was having a wrapper view, which would load other views through initialize and other functions.

So like: (Horrible psuedocode ahead)

```
Master View{
     initialize: make item1
                 make item2
}

item1{}

item2{}
```

edit:

I would comment if possible, but my ranking isn't high enough.